# Angular view not updated after scope value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a new JSON object at a particular index in a json array that is attached to angular scope from external javascript method. It is rendered in view using ng-repeat. My issue is when i push a new json it is just added to the scope and there is no changes in my view.

This is my js code for adding the new json to scope:

```
   function updateScope(index,json){
      var $scope = angular.element($("#content_inner_wrapper_2col")).scope();
      var scope = $scope.historydata; //JSONArray    
      scope[index].interactionStatusList.push(json);
       $scope.$apply(function(){
         $scope.historydata = scope;
     });
     }
```

My HTML code snippet where the scope.historydata is rendered:

```
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="historyTable">

   <tr ng-class="{historyclicked : $first}" data-ng-repeat="history in historydata track by $index" id="{{history.interactionId}}_historyid" ng-click="showMessageInfo(history.interactionId)">        
     <td class="sender">{{history.userId}}</td>
     <td style="width:60%"><div style="height:20px" ng-bind-html=history.comment>             </td>
     <td class="date_time"><div style="position:relative; height:20px; padding-right:15px; overflow:hidden;">{{history.dateAddedWithTimeZone}}</div></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

I checked in my console where my scope is updated but the view is not. Please post your views

Comment: what happens if you just use update the `$scope.historydata` array, and use `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: The new json that i attach to the scope are not updated in the view but any modification to the already existing data in $scope.historydata is updated in the view.

Comment: Would you add the html so I can get a better idea of context?

Comment: Can u share the problem in jsfiddle or plunker etc?

Comment: This is very confusing: you're using "history" object and "emptyHistoryData" inside your template, but you set "historydata" inside your scope. Please check your naming because this cant work.

Comment: emptyHistoryData is different and it is not the concren here, history in historydata is rendered using data-ng-repeat which holds my json.

Comment: You aren't changing any items in the collection, you're just updating some child value of one of the objects in the collection. So, angular doesn't think that anything has changed in the collection, and doesn't re-render anything. Easy ways to solve this: $scope.historydata = scope.slice(0); but it really isn't a solution because it has bad performance.